# Backup Sharepoint 2010 (using Powershell - Backup-SPFarm)

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008

I asked this on ServerFault, but didn't get any reply's, I know it's command line, but they should still be able to answer it, anyone here have any idea's?

I've ran the following ([task description](http://imperfectit.blogspot.com/2010/03/automate-sharepoint-2010-farm-backups.html)):

```
> Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
> Backup-SPFarm -Directory E:\Backups -BackupMethod Full
```

But get this error:

```
Backup-SPFarm : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:14
+ Backup-SPFarm <<<<  -Directory \\SHAREPOINTSERV\Backups -BackupMethod full
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletBackupFarm:SPCmdletBackupFarm) [Backup-SPFarm], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletBackupFarm
```

I can backup manually through the Admin site, so all the services/permissions are setup correctly.

I [can't find much helpful info on this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/a9b89113-1f27-4f95-a575-e07aa10caa49#7e41287f-129c-4f83-98cf-f7fd4c9eed97) does anyone know why I'm getting this error message?

- running SQL Server 2008 R2 and Win2008 Standard (x64).
- tried setting the directory to a UNC path and a local path.
- tried `set-executionpolicy ByPass` (and RemoteSigned)
- I'm logged on as a user with enterprise admin security credentials
- SharePoint & SQL Server are installed on the same machine

Not sure if relevent, but I'm a developer and have never used power-shell before (nor has it been used on this machine before)... so my only guess is there is some sort of pre-requisite that I am supposed to have run or know about?

EDIT: 
VERBOSE OUTPUT

```
PS E:\Backups\Script> Backup-SPFarm -Directory E:\Backups -BackupMethod Full -Verbose
VERBOSE: Leaving BeginProcessing Method of Backup-SPFarm.
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Backup-SPFarm" on Target "SHAREPOINTSERV".
Backup-SPFarm : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:14
+ Backup-SPFarm <<<<  -Directory E:\Backups -BackupMethod Full -Verbose
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...mdletBackupFarm:SPCmdletBackupFarm) [Backup-SPFarm], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletBackupFarm


VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Backup-SPFarm.
VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Backup-SPFarm.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as I suspected this was something simple, but took a long time to work out (thanks to Microsoft's amazingly useful error message :p )

I had opened Sharepoint Management Shell before, but as a different user, which meant I did see a vital message that would point me in the right direction...

When I set up the server, there was no need to log into SQL Server other than to set up the service accounts (I think I logged in as my user, not the enterprise admin) and the enterprise admin didn't have any SQL Server permissions.

I suspected the line `Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` hadn't worked properly, even though it said it did.

As I was trying to create a powershell script through the powershell editor I never opened Sharepoint Management Shell as the admin user I had logged in as.

Once I had seen the message in Sharepoint Management Shell, [I googled it](http://www.sharepointassist.com/2010/01/29/the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered/), and problem solved.

It would have been nice of Microsoft to display this instead of the object reference message!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the SQL Server and the SharePoint products installed on the same system? Or is this a farm deployment with multiple servers?

In case of a farm deployment, you have the provide a UNC path of the backup folder. At least, that is what

```
Get-Help Backup-SPFarm -Parameter Directory
```

says.

Also, can you post the output of

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory E:\Backups -BackupMethod Full -Verbose
```

Comment: SQL Server is on the same machine

Comment: I've edited my answer to include verbose output, but it doesn't shed any light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

In the question on the technet site, you have dumped a stack trace that shows an error accessing the configuration DB info from the registry (at, I guess, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDB).

Could you check the permissions of this key and the identity of the w3wp processes ?

Comment: Sorry if that was a bit misleading, that isn't my question. Someone else posted that.

Comment: Wow, I am the one being sorry. I should have read the question better. When you wrote the question, I had tried the cmdlet backup and it worked on my VM, so, sorry, no idea why it does not work.

Comment: Strange, maybe I am missing a prerequisite of some kind, but I don't know what it would be.